# Laravel validation find input name with JQuery using dot array syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

How can I find in JQuery input by name, if I have dot array syntax from Laravel?

Input example:

```
<input type="text" name="Payments[0][1][Amount]">
<input type="text" name="Reservations[0][Date]">
```

Laravel validation response from ajax request:

```
errors: {
  Payments.0.1.Amount: "Field is required",
  Reservations.0.Date: "Field should be date"
}
```

Problem: How can I looping through errors array in javascript access input names, if I only have array dot names?

For example, transform `Payments.0.1.Amount` to `Payments[0][1][Amount]`, or `Reservations.0.Date` to `Reservations[0][Date]`

```
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(errors)) {
     key = somehowParseDotInputToArray(key); // how? :)
   $('#app input[name="' + key + '"]').append( '<p class="error">'+ value +'</p>' );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have allready found solution, maybe someone also helps :)

```
function DotArrayToJs(str){
  var splittedStr = str.split('.');

  return splittedStr.length == 1 ? str : (splittedStr[0] + '[' + splittedStr.splice(1).join('][') + ']');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply split the name in an error object from `.` . Using `var $nameArr = name.split('.');`

Suppose `name = Reservations.0.Date` it will be like 
`let nameArr = ['Reservations','0','Date']`

then make name as you want so

```
var newName = $nameArr[0] + '['+ $nameArr[1] +']' + '[' +$nameArr[2] + ']';
```

newName will look like `Reservations[0][Date]`

loop this process for all name variable and make new error object.

Comment: Hi, it will not work with 'Payments.0.1.Amount' and with input without array, for example -> 'Payments'. You can see my own answer, there are solved all this issues :)

Comment: for this you need to concat $nameArr[3]

Answer (score 0):

Juste in case someone has multi-level arrays

```js
 function getFieldnameFromLaravelDotName(laravelDotName) {

  let parts = laravelDotName.split(".");
  let fieldName = "";
  let prefix = "";
  let suffix = "";
  parts.forEach((part, i) => {

   if (fieldName != "") {

    prefix = "[";
    suffix = "]";

   }

   fieldName += prefix + part + suffix;

  });

  return fieldName;

 }
  
  console.log(getFieldnameFromLaravelDotName("noDotInThis"));
  console.log(getFieldnameFromLaravelDotName("one.level"));
  console.log(getFieldnameFromLaravelDotName("many.level.array.plop"));
```